QGIS wrong filter result when using "." instead of ","
I am using the graphical modeler in QGIS.
I need to extract all water objects within a county which are bigger than 5,133 ha. After clipping the nationwide OSM water objects to the county. I let the computer calculate the area of each objects in hectar with $area/10000. So far so good. All water bodies are clipped and the areas calculated.

The problem occurs while executing the Extract by attribut function. If I set the filter value to 5,1333 (ha) all smaller objects are filtered but a big lake with more than 31 ha as well.
When setting the value to 5.1333 (mind the "." instead of ",") the created shape contains the big lake.
What is the reason for this and how to avoid it ?
If the "," is the problem in the first place, I expect an error message. This is the case if I try to filter by hand in QGIS. A SQL error is displayed and no objects are filtered, with the modeler no error is popping up and just the big water bodies is missing.


Always use a dot when using numerical fields, thats independent from your system locale. Your system locale just displays a comma instead of a dot in previews, the attribute table and so on. But technically it is always a dot.
